# Famous five-minute WordPress installation process After website migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

After successfully migrating all of the files and the DB, connected WP to the DB in the wp-config, i receive the  famous five-minute WordPress installation process, and it wants to overwrite my website

Triead all in one migration plugin, but that BS isn't working either, stuck at uploading the backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `wp-config.php` file because you might have a different `$table_prefix` from your phpMyadmin > DB > table prefix

You can also check this SO post:
[Wordpress keeps redirecting to install-php after migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827164/wordpress-keeps-redirecting-to-install-php-after-migration?rq=2)

Let me know how it went and I hope this resolves your issue!

Comment: Thanks bro, I don't understand how this sh!t is working on one server, but not on another, CHEEEERS!

Comment: Yes, `table_prefix` varies server to server. I'm glad to hear that it's working!

Comment: Now i got a new problem, cant access `wp-admin` after successfully logging in, i get `Sorry but you can't enter this page` error

Comment: I would like to support you however the issue of your comment is a new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as a new question and include all detailed information. Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it.