# Recover Wordpress Website from Database and WordPress Files

Tags: php, wordpress, ionos

My web hosting provider somehow removed my website. Now I have only the following data from my removed website:

1. A copy of the database (.dump file)
2. A copy of the Webserver folder of the WordPress website.

I tried the following to reconstruct my website (tried locally and also online):

1. Create an empty database and import a copy of the database (.sql file by just renaming the .dump file)
2. In the wp-config.php, inside the folder of WordPress folder, change the database info (user, pass, ...)
3. Try to access the website. It tries to install WordPress from scratch.
4. Even though I tried to install WordPress, but there is still an empty "Hello World" website with all previously installed plugins.
5. Updating plugins and Themes also did not help.

My hosting provider is IONOS, Germany.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the same tables prefix? see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827164/wordpress-keeps-redirecting-to-install-php-after-migration - I would also consider different hosting, no good will come when provider deletes content...

Comment: Thanks @ButcherFromHell! That was exactly the problem. Saved hours of hours from me!